# Function applied to Raster cell values also executes to NA values in R

Tags: raster, r, terra, fuzzy-logic

I'm trying to fuzzify a Terra SpatRaster object using a Fuzzy membership function created with FuzzyR package using the method Terra::app, but the function is also aplied to NA values. How can I avoid this problem?

```r
FRea_0C_rast <- rasterize(FRea_0C, area_rast, "FRea_value")
```

[image: FRea_0C_rast]

```r
FRea_0C_rast_funfuzz <- genmf("trimf", c(0, 0, 7))

FRea_0C_rast_fuzz <- app(FRea_0C_rast, FRea_0C_rast_funfuzz)
```

[image: FRea_0C_rast_fuzz]

I've tried to include arguments such as na.rm but they don't work on the app function. Also, I could crop the raster to the original extent.

Is there a method to avoid the problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set cells in output raster `r2` to `NA` where there's corresponding `NA` values in input raster `r`, you can do:

```
# test data
r = rast(matrix(1:12,3,4))
r[c(1,2,5,6)]=NA
r2 = sqrt(r) # or some other processing...

r2[is.na(r)] = NA
```

(This is a null op for the `sqrt` function because `sqrt(NA) = NA` but I can't think of a simple example)

The computation will still be done on all cells, you just throw it away afterwards.

If the computation is expensive and you don't want to do it on `NA` input values at all, then take the non-NA values, work on them, then replace into the raster:

```
# test data
r = rast(matrix(1:12,3,4))
r[c(1,2,5,6)]=NA

# square-root non-NA values
r[!is.na(r)] = sqrt(r[!is.na(r)])
```

Note this stomps on the original `r` raster, so maybe copy first:

```
r2 = r
r2[!is.na(r)] = sqrt(r[!is.na(r)])
```

where `sqrt` is my function. For a single layer, I think `r2 = f(r1)` is equivalent to `r2 = app(r1, f)`.